# Менять на ходу анимацию Android

Tags: android, анимация, binding

Хочу привязать поле модели с параметрами анимации к выполняемой анимации, чтобы при изменении например duration при следующем цикле анимации duration была применена без остановки и пересоздании анимации, пока использую такой код, по кнопке к элементу ImageView применяется анимация:

```
case R.id.btnScale: {
                FragmentContainerView fr = findViewById(R.id.frScale);
                fr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                imgElementAnimation.clearAnimation();

                // получаем ссылку на фрагмент-приемник
                ScaleFragment fragmentScale = (ScaleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frScale);

                //получаем модель настроек выбранной анимации
                assert fragmentScale != null;
                ScaleAnimationModel model = fragmentScale.scaleViewModel.getModel();

                //подготовим анимацию с настройками из модели
                ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(model.getFromXScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale, model.getToXScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale,
                        model.getFromYScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale, model.getToYScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, model.getPivotX() * ScaleAnimationModel.PivotXscale / 100.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, model.getPivotY() * ScaleAnimationModel.PivotYscale / 100.0f);
                scale.setDuration(model.getDuration());
                scale.setRepeatMode(model.isRepeatMode() ? 2 : 1);
                scale.setRepeatCount(model.getRepeatCount());
                scale.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

                imgElementAnimation.startAnimation(scale);
            }
            break;
```

Что нужно сделать чтоб изменения применялись на ходу. Такой себе Проект чтоб поиграться с анимацией, да и лучше понять про взаимодействие параметров в Android.

Comment: отменить текущую анимацию, установить новые параметры и запустить снова

Comment: приведенный код это и делает, суть вопроса при активной анимации , которая выполняется несколько раз(в идеале бесконечно) поменять параметр и с учетом его нового значения сразу применить к новой итерации отработки анимации, исключить нажатие кнопки как есть сейчас.

Comment: повесь слушатель на анимацию, когда она заканчивается - запускай метод которые ее стартует

Comment: в этом и проблема, не пойму как завязать изменение данных в модели и слушателя на окончание анимации, да и слушатель на окончание анимации тоже что то не получается корректно повесить

Answer (score 0):

Сделай метод, вроде такого

```
    private void startAnim(ImageView imgElementAnimation) {
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(model.getFromXScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale, model.getToXScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale,
            model.getFromYScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale, model.getToYScale() / ScaleAnimationModel.Scalescale,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, model.getPivotX() * ScaleAnimationModel.PivotXscale / 100.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, model.getPivotY() * ScaleAnimationModel.PivotYscale / 100.0f);
    scale.setDuration(model.getDuration());
    scale.setRepeatMode(model.isRepeatMode() ? 2 : 1);
    scale.setRepeatCount(model.getRepeatCount());
    scale.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    scale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (model.isStopAnim) {
                startAnim(imgElementAnimation);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    imgElementAnimation.startAnimation(scale);
}
```

Вызывай его у себя в onClickListener()
Ну и зачем хранить модель внутри фрагмента, непонятно. Вынеси ее отдельно, чтоб всем удобно было обращаться, а лучше использую стандартное решение https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: Можешь еще в onAnimationRepeat проверять, изменилась ли моделька, и если изменилась - перезапускать анимацию

Comment: У меня сделан фрагмент с установкой всех интересующих параметров анимации, к фрагменту привязана модель, которую я использую для создания анимации, анимаций может быть несколько, поэтому использую AnimationSet и создание и отработка анимации происходит нормально, но чтобы увидеть как измениться анимация при других параметрах мне приходится нажимать кнопку и пересоздавать анимацию. Хотелось сделать вариант без нажатия на кнопку, особенно когда анимация бесконечна.

Comment: Не привязывай модель к фрагменту. Не хочешь нажимать на кнопку - привяжись к другим событиям, сделай слушатель на liveData например.